# How to detect the collision nodes name in skspritekit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I would like to detect the nodes name my player node colides with. Is that possible?

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    
    let collision: UInt32 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    
    for i in CollectionObject {
        if collision == Player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask | i.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask{
            print("hit the object") //here I would like to print the nodes name                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
contact.bodyA.node?.name
```

and

```
contact.bodyB.node?.name
```

to get the names of the 2 nodes colliding with each other.

So if your player node has a name, then you could use something like the below:

```
if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "PlayerName"  {
    print(contact.bodyB.node?.name)
} else if contact.bodyB.node?.name == "PlayerName" {
    print(contact.bodyA.node?.name)
}
```